# How to access a network directory

Tags: macos, network-shares

I have the following network directory:

```
\\XXX.XXX.X.XXX\name\
```

I can access it without a problem on my windows pc but I have no idea to get there with this mac because I want to use it to backup stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> in Finder and type `smb://XXX.XXX.X.XXX/` or `smb://XXX.XXX.X.XXX/name`

Comment: control-k has no effect in finder

Comment: That's command-k, not control-k.  The "control" key is the one with the clover and/or apple icons on it.

Answer (score 0):

Command-K and smb://XXX.XXX.X.XXX/name